# In Rasa stack, during mitie installation, attribute error, file not found error and other errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, rasa-nlu, rasa

(venv) C:\Users\qwerty\Bankbot\rasa>pip install mitie
Collecting mitie
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/80/e9/4481c5e6233b8b93acccaacf595bc8e11f40d6ac2e6f6e70b7a62693f9ea/mitie-0.7.36.tar.gz
Building wheels for collected packages: mitie
  Building wheel for mitie (setup.py) ... error
  Complete output from command c:\users\qwerty\bankbot\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pfcl6b4q\mitie\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-1jff998y --python-tag cp37:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pfcl6b4q\mitie\setup.py", line 44, in get_cmake_version
      out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
    File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
      **kwargs).stdout
    File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
      with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**
      restore_signals, start_new_session)
    File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
      startupinfo)
  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "", line 1, in 
    File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pfcl6b4q\mitie\setup.py", line 67, in 
      'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
    File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\wheel\bdist_wheel.py", line 223, in run
      self.run_command('build')
    File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pfcl6b4q\mitie\setup.py", line 16, in run
      if LooseVersion(self.get_cmake_version()) < '3.1.0':
    File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pfcl6b4q\mitie\setup.py", line 47, in get_cmake_version
      ", ".join(e.name for e in self.extensions))
    File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 103, in **getattr**
      raise AttributeError(attr)
  AttributeError: extensions

---

Failed building wheel for mitie
  Running setup.py clean for mitie
Failed to build mitie
Installing collected packages: mitie
  Running setup.py install for mitie ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\qwerty\bankbot\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pfcl6b4q\mitie\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qzh_imsa\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\qwerty\bankbot\venv\include\site\python3.7\mitie:
    running install
    running build
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pfcl6b4q\mitie\setup.py", line 44, in get_cmake_version
        out = subprocess.check_output(['cmake', '--version'])
      File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 395, in check_output
        **kwargs).stdout
      File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 472, in run
        with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in **init**
        restore_signals, start_new_session)
      File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
        startupinfo)
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pfcl6b4q\mitie\setup.py", line 67, in <module>
    'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.5',
  File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "c:\users\qwerty\bankbot\venv\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
    return orig.install.run(self)
  File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
    self.run_command('build')
  File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
    self.distribution.run_command(command)
  File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pfcl6b4q\mitie\setup.py", line 16, in run
    if LooseVersion(self.get_cmake_version()) < '3.1.0':
  File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pfcl6b4q\mitie\setup.py", line 47, in get_cmake_version
    ", ".join(e.name for e in self.extensions))
  File "C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 103, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(attr)
AttributeError: extensions

----------------------------------------
```

Command "c:\users\qwerty\bankbot\venv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pfcl6b4q\mitie\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-qzh_imsa\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\qwerty\bankbot\venv\include\site\python3.7\mitie" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\qwerty\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pfcl6b4q\mitie\

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged it with `rasa`, I assume you are trying to use MITIE with rasa.

These are the steps to take. I am giving it here for use from a clean mini-conda environment, on Ubuntu:

```
(base) $ conda create --name test-mitie-install python=3.7
(base) $ conda activate test-mitie-install
(test-mitie-install) $ pip install git+https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE.git
(test-mitie-install) $ pip install rasa[mitie]
```

After this, you still have to download the MITIE models, as described in the rasa documentation on rasa.com .

I did see from your logs that it is installing from a cached copy:

```
...Collecting mitie Using cached...
```

If the installation as described here is not working for you, try to use `pip install --no-cache-dir ....`